# Encrypt any pdf in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, pdf-generation

Is it possible to load external pdf with access and save it encrypted with bullzip?

I'm using [this code](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28561834/password-protect-a-pdf-document-in-msaccess-vba.html) for encrypting reports as pdf, but have problems adapting it for pdf files.

Comment: Not using Bullzip, since that's a PDF printer, not an encryption program (unless you want to open and print the PDF to another PDF which is inefficient). [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html), however, has a commandline interface. With what you learned in your previous question, you should be able to call it from VBA.

Comment: ok, got it, Tx. Shell ("java -jar c:\razpis\pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar Encrypt -O 123 -U 456 c:\razpis\test.pdf")

Comment: Note that shell doesn't generate an error if the program you're calling encounters one. When debugging, you will want to open a command window and try there. Glad it worked